# Change color of Selected-Unfocused ComboBox Item in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change the color of `SelectedUnfocused(Item marked with red border in image below)` Item in ComboBox.

So, I tried to change the control template of a combobox.

**Before Copying ControlTemplate from MSDN :**

[image]

**After Copying ControlTemplate from MSDN :**

[image]

So, that template has changed the whole look of my control. I don't want to change those colors.

[Here is the MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the template that I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add only `ComboBoxItem` style from the linked page and `relevant brushes` used in the style**. No need to overwrite complete template.

Copy/Paste only this much of code in your XAML and you are good to go:

```
<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color> <-- Update color here

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="2"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have tried that just now after seeing answer given by HighCore. If I do that or if I paste whole Control-Template I have found one issue. I have lost the color of MouseOver. So, now If I mouse-over any item in ComboBox, its color is transparent/white. How can I change it?

Comment: I have got it. I have to use new VisualStateGroup with name = CommonStates and under that I have to define two Visual States named Normal and MouseOver. Inside that I have changed the brush colors. Also I used the above code that you mentioned. Thanks for solving my problem again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change only the `ComboBoxItem` style, and not the `ComboBox` style, simply remove the `Style TargetType="ComboBox"` from your XAML and leave only the relevant `Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem` from the linked MSDN page.